# Self or complex Weyl representation in Polchinski

Tags: representation-theory, spinors, spacetime-dimensions, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

In p.433 of Polchinski String theory volume 2, he said that:

In $d$ spacetime dimension, for the chirality matrix $\Gamma$,

For $d = 2 \mod 4$, each Weyl representation is its own conjugate. ($B \Gamma B^{-1} =+\Gamma^* $)

For $d = 0 \mod 4$, each Weyl representation is conjugate to the other. ($B \Gamma B^{-1} =-\Gamma^* $)

I suppose these correspond to the self or complex in his p.434 Table B 1.

However, what do these self or complex really mean?

[image]

p.s. Typo corrected.